# How to convert Json to Map in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have json data but i need to convert the json to Map in dart/flutter.
The json data is :

```
{"kabupaten": [
        {
            "jec_kabupaten_id": "71",
            "jec_propinsi_id": "8",
            "name": "Aceh Barat"
        },
        {
            "jec_kabupaten_id": "76",
            "jec_propinsi_id": "8",
            "name": "Aceh Barat Daya"
        }, 
        {
            "jec_kabupaten_id": "91",
            "jec_propinsi_id": "9",
            "name": "Medan"
        }, 
         {
            "jec_kabupaten_id": "92",
            "jec_propinsi_id": "9",
            "name": "Sinabung"
        }
    ]}
```

I want to convert to this Map with dart/flutter:

```
 {
   "8":{
      "71":"Aceh Barat",
      "76":"Aceh Barat Daya",
      "68":"Aceh Besar"
   },
   "9":{
      "91":"Medan",
      "92":"Sinabung"
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Converting Json map of a map to List<Object> in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893854/flutter-converting-json-map-of-a-map-to-listobject-in-flutter)

Comment: If you have access to backend, I think its better to group that from backend using query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to transform the data using `fold` for example.

```dart
void main() {
  const data = {
    "kabupaten": [
      {
        "jec_kabupaten_id": "71",
        "jec_propinsi_id": "8",
        "name": "Aceh Barat",
      },
      {
        "jec_kabupaten_id": "76",
        "jec_propinsi_id": "8",
        "name": "Aceh Barat Daya",
      },
      {
        "jec_kabupaten_id": "91",
        "jec_propinsi_id": "9",
        "name": "Medan",
      },
      {
        "jec_kabupaten_id": "92",
        "jec_propinsi_id": "9",
        "name": "Sinabung",
      },
    ],
  };

  final result = data['kabupaten']?.fold<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>(
    {},
    (prev, elem) => prev
      ..[elem['jec_propinsi_id']!] ??= {}
      ..[elem['jec_propinsi_id']!]![elem['jec_kabupaten_id']!] = elem['name']!,
  );

  print(result);
}
```

An alternative would be to build up the result in a for loop:

```dart
final result = <String, Map<String, String>>{};
for (final elem in data['kabupaten'] ?? []) {
  result[elem['jec_propinsi_id']!] ??= {};
  result[elem['jec_propinsi_id']!]![elem['jec_kabupaten_id']!] = elem['name']!;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help @mmcdon20